# Passed Aggregate Results and assigning to values

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

I have aggregate results I am passing to a method in a class.
Here is my Results query:

```
AggregateResult[] groupedOLIs = [ 
     select SUM(TotalPrice)TotalPriceSum,
         MIN(StartDate__c)StartMin,
         MAX(endDate__c)EndMax,
         PackageAdId__c
         from OpportunityLineItem 
         where OpportunityId = :opp.id
         GROUP BY PackageAdId__c
     ];
```

My method takes this in and I want to assign the packageid to a string in a for loop for further processing:

```
public List<Revenue_Schedule__c> Compile(List<AggregateResult> oLIs, List<DeliveryByAdIdByMonth> delByAdByMonthList, Opportunity opp){   
for(AggregateResult oli : oLIs){
String mappingAlias=oli.PackageAdId__c;     
more processing....
```

but I am told PackageAdId__c variable does not exist. It was returned in the query and grouped by.

```
String mappingAlias=oli.id;
```

Does not throw this error. Am I not allowed to use field?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should access fields from `AggregateResult` in different way, using `get` method:

```
String mappingAlias = (String) oli.get('PackageAdId__c');
```

refer to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

Comment: Odd - this tells me 'Illegal assignment from Object to String' - is this b/c I am trying to get field that they are grouped by?

Comment: @jaw999 I've updated my answer. You need to do casting to proper type